# Datatable header drop to body after gridview select command change

Tags: css, asp.net

I have gridview table that uses dynamic selectcommand based on text box data.

```
                                        <div class="card-body pa-0">
                                        <div class="table-wrap">
                                            <asp:GridView ID="SpNLog" runat="server" UseAccessibleHeader="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="MyDS1" CssClass="table is-striped" Style="width: 100%; font-size: small;">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Spo_Nam" HeaderText="Sponsor name" SortExpression=""></asp:BoundField>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Biv" HeaderText="Biowaiver" SortExpression=""></asp:BoundField>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Biq" HeaderText="Bioeq." SortExpression=""></asp:BoundField>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Stb" HeaderText="Stability" SortExpression=""></asp:BoundField>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Numb" HeaderText="Total" SortExpression=""></asp:BoundField>
                                                </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                            <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="MyDS1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Select command is added on page load and with asp button, its work fine after page load, but after using the button to filter the data, the header row drops to the table body
Can any one help

"on page load code"

```
string SeC = "My full SELECT SQL command";
MyDS1.SelectCommand = SeC;
SpNLog.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
SpNLog.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
```

"Click event code"

```
string SeC = "My full SELECT SQL command with filter";
MyDS1.SelectCommand = SeC;
SpNLog.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
SpNLog.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
SpNLog.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
SpNLog.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
```

"Data table script"

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SpNLog').DataTable({
            scrollY: '40vh',
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false,
            searching: false,
            info: false,
            'columnDefs': [
                {
                    "targets": [1, 2, 3, 4], // your case first column
                    "className": "text-center",
                },
            ]
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: don't know why but its fixed after using Pre_Render_Complete event

Comment: protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
        {
                SpNLog.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }